# how to call scheduled webjob in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I downloaded some azure webjob examples and got confused. What I want is fairly easy:
Given a specific time (once a day) controlled by Cron syntax, I would like to call a method to do some heavy staff.

From the example I downloaded, there is always a Main program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JobHost host = new JobHost();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

Then you can define a trigger (e.g. a QueueTrigger)

```
 public static void GenerateThumbnail(
    [QueueTrigger("thumbnailrequest")] BlobInformation blobInfo,
    [Blob("images/{BlobName}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream input,
    [Blob("images/{BlobNameWithoutExtension}_thumbnail.jpg")] CloudBlockBlob outputBlob)
    {
}
```

However, I don't need a queue item to trigger something, all I need is that when my Cron time is matched, My method (say it is Functions.DoThis()) will be fired.

Unfortunately I just couldn't find a way to do it. Can someone help?

Comment: This is a perfect use case for Azure Functions.  Have you looked this approach?  Using the HTTP trigger you would invoke a URL like this :  https://{function app name}.azurewebsites.net/api/{function name}   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-overview/

Comment: Hi, My code takes a while to finish. Will the http trigger timeout? For example, I tried to use an azure scheduler to call my url before, but the scheduler keep on reporting timeout error, even though the url was indeed called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a Timer Trigger, e.g.

```
// Runs once every 5 minutes
public static void CronJob([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cron job fired!");
}
```

See [this page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/README.md#timertrigger) for more info.